# What is [1,2,3,4][1,2] in javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone explains the above question with explanation. I tried it console and the answer coming is 3

```
[1,2,3,4][1,2] //consoles 3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[1,2,3,4]` is an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Creating_an_array).

`1,2` is two numbers with a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) between them, so resolves to `2`.

So you are getting index 2 (the third item) from the array.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var property = (1,2);
var result = array[property];

console.log({ array: array, property: property, result: result });
```

Answer (score 11):

The first `[1,2,3,4]` is an array of 4 numbers.

The second `[1,2]` is a [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) (used here to access an item of the above array).

Inside that bracket notation you have a [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) that evaluates to its right most expression `2`.

So:

```
[1,2,3,4][1,2]
```

is the same as:

```
[1,2,3,4][2]
```

which is the same as:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr[2];
```

Comment: this answer is more clear!

Answer (score 7):

It's an immediately invoked array with a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The **comma operator** evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

for the index.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4][1, 2]
```

resolves to

```
[1, 2, 3, 4][2] // 3
```